# I have a source document:

Tags: xslt-2.0

```
I have a source document:

<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<Circuit revision="B" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Block name="Design">
        <Data>
            <Layer name="INDEX_4" Function="PLANE"></Layer>
            <Layer name="INDEX_9" Function="CORE"></Layer>
            <Group name="PRIMARY">
                <SubGroup name="GROUP_PRIMARY">
                    <SubLayer Ref="INDEX_4" thickness="0.0350"></SubLayer>
                    <SubLayer Ref="INDEX_9" thickness="0.1000"></SubLayer>
                </SubGroup>
            </Group>
        </Data>
    </Block>
</Circuit>
```

This stylesheet using current() extracts the corresponding thickness:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
<xsl:template match="/Circuit/Block/Data/Layer">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
           <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="Function">
          <xsl:value-of select="@Function"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:value-of select="/Circuit/Block/Data/Group/SubGroup/SubLayer[@Ref=current()/@name]/@thickness"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's the second stylesheet to extract the PREVIOUS thickness value:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
<xsl:template match="/Circuit/Block/Data/Layer">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
           <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="Function">
          <xsl:value-of select="@Function"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:value-of select="/Circuit/Block/Data/Group/SubGroup/SubLayer[@Ref=preceding-sibling::*[1]/@name]/@thickness"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

In both cases I get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Layer id="INDEX_4" Function="PLANE">0.0350</Layer>
    <Layer id="INDEX_9" Function="CORE">0.1000</Layer>
```

I tried the preceding-sibling to get the preceding value - I guess the question is "What is the context of the preceding-sibling?"

Is it the group with the Layer element or the group with the SubLayer element?

Thanks

Ralph B

Answer (score 0):

Within any predicate the context item is the selected item in the step before the predicate so with `SubLayer[@Ref=preceding-sibling::*[1]/@name]` the context for both `@Ref` as well as `preceding-sibling::*[1]/@name` is the `SubLayer` element. If you want to select relative to the currently matched `Layer` element in the template you need to use `current()/preceding-sibling::*[1]/@name` inside the predicate.

Comment: Martin,
That's a life saver! I would never have worked that out - and I've trawled through many books and web sites for it. Is there somewhere that gives more examples of such expressions?

Comment: XSLT and XPath 1.0 are more that 15 years old, XSLT and XPath 2.0 are nearly 10 years old by now so there is for sure lots of tutorial and books around, see for instance https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/xslt-foundations-part1 or http://www.cranesoftwrights.com/training/index.htm#ptux